# Thread in C++ not working as expected. Throwing Unknown error

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi, mutex

I am writing an example C++ code on Raspberry Pi to practice C++ threads. My simple code is provided below

```
// Standard C++ Libraries file, time and memory
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
// Standard C++ Libraries for multi-threading
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
static mutex cout_lock;

static atomic<bool> main_done;

void func1(){
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
        cout_lock.lock();
        cout<<"In Fun1"<<"\n";
        cout_lock.unlock();
        if(main_done.load()){
            cout<<"Stopping Func1"<<"\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void func2(){
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
        cout_lock.lock();
        cout<<"In Fun2"<<"\n";
        cout_lock.unlock();
        if(main_done.load()){
            cout<<"Stopping Func2"<<"\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    main_done.store(false);
    thread fn1(func1);
    thread fn2(func2);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 5; ++idx)
    {
        cout<<idx<<"\n";
        sleep(1);
    }
    main_done.store(true);
    fn1.join();
    fn2.join();

    return 1;
}
```

When I compile and run the code I get the following error and I am unable to figure out what might be causing this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1225166128
Aborted
```

I compiled the code using the C++ flags `-Ofast` and `-pthread` and then get the expected output from func1 and func2 while printing to the terminal

```
0
In Fun1
In Fun2
1
In Fun1
In Fun2
2
In Fun1
In Fun2
3
In Fun1
In Fun2
4
In Fun1
In Fun2
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1225166128
Aborted
```

Edit:
When I wrapped the main inside a try catch as follows

```
    try{
        main_done.store(false);
        thread fn1(func1);
        thread fn2(func2);
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 5; ++idx)
        {
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lockMain(cout_lock);
                cout<<idx<<"\n";
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        main_done.store(true);
        fn1.join();
        fn2.join();
    }catch(std::exception const& e){
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }

return 0;
```

I get the following output

```
0
In Fun1
In Fun2
1
In Fun1
In Fun2
2
In Fun1
In Fun2
3
In Fun1
In Fun2
4
In Fun1
In Fun2
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

Which still doesn't make sense

Comment: You should not be calling `lock()`/`unlock()` directly. Use `std::unique_lock`, `std::scoped_lock`, or `std::lock_guard` instead. Also, your main thread is accessing `cout` without locking the mutex. But none of this should be causing the failure, unless Rasberry's `cout` is not thread-safe to begin with (it should be)

Comment: Fyi, the main thread  isn't the only one hitting `cout` without the mutex latched. The workers do as well during their exit strat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just learned about the unique_lock and will be using that going forward but as you already mentioned that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You could always dive further and surround your current `main` body, not including the `return` in a `try{}` block, putting a `catch(std::exception const& e) {  std::cerr << e.what() << '\n'; }` afterward and see what gives. I'd also suggest returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` just because.

Comment: Where and how should I return `EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Comment: The default constructor of `std::atomic` does not perform initialization prior to C++20. You should use a constructor that sets a value, i.e. `static atomic<bool> main_done(false);`. The initialization may perform more actions than just the store, e.g. if the atomic is implemented with locks. Other than that I don't see anything wrong with your code that should result in the error.

Comment: @WhozCraig after I wrapped the `main` body in `try` and `catch` as you suggested I get `terminate called without an active exception` messaged.

Comment: @user3746381 `EXIT_SUCCESS` is a macro defined in `<cstdlib>` which evaluates to the exit code (i.e. the value you return from `main`) that is considered a successful exit on the platform. On POSIX platforms for example `1` would be considered failure and only `0` success. But you can always return `0` for success, no matter what `EXIT_SUCCESS` is.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the reason for the error. After going through countless link it seemed the way I was linking `-pthread` in my cmake file. I am using something like the following now

```
# To enable threading
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_LIBRARIES} Threads::Threads)
```